# Google like customize and preview embedded map in my site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i whant to have something similar like googles customize and preview embedded map. is it possible that users just find location on the map, type in the size they want and just copy the generated code?

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is that you want to allow people to select and save a custom Google map of their own within your app.

A simple way to do so would be using Google maps APIto create a map inside a container dom element. You would then allow user to resize the container element which would essentially allow them to position the map and also their chosen size.

When the user is finished resizing and positioning, you would need to make another call to the API to get the current lat/long of the map as well as getting the dimensions of the container. With the lat/long and container dimensions saved, this should be enough information for you to save the users custom map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for response, but i was hoping for an example becouse i dont have too much programming experience...